# Wildfly suspending intermittently my web application

Tags: java, postgresql, jakarta-ee, wildfly

Wildfly are suspending intermittently my java web application. This occur often one time in the week.

I'm running my service with the following configuration:

Ubuntu 16 8GB

Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2640 v3 @ 2.60GHz

Web Application:

Wildfly 14

Java 11

JavaEE 8

Postgresql

```
2019-08-08 07:35:14,619 ERROR [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) WFLYDS0012: Scan of /opt/wildfly-14.0.1.Final/standalone/deployments threw Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: WFLYDS0032: Failed to list files in directory /opt/wildfly-14.0.1.Final/standalone/deployments. Check that the contents of the directory are readable.
    at org.jboss.as.deployment-scanner@6.0.2.Final//org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner.FileSystemDeploymentService.listDirectoryChildren(FileSystemDeploymentService.java:1365)
    at org.jboss.as.deployment-scanner@6.0.2.Final//org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner.FileSystemDeploymentService.scanDirectory(FileSystemDeploymentService.java:846)
    at org.jboss.as.deployment-scanner@6.0.2.Final//org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner.FileSystemDeploymentService.scan(FileSystemDeploymentService.java:598)
    at org.jboss.as.deployment-scanner@6.0.2.Final//org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner.FileSystemDeploymentService.scan(FileSystemDeploymentService.java:493)
    at org.jboss.as.deployment-scanner@6.0.2.Final//org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner.FileSystemDeploymentService$DeploymentScanRunnable.run(FileSystemDeploymentService.java:255)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:305)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:305)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.3.2.Final//org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:485)
Caused by: java.nio.file.FileSystemException: /opt/wildfly-14.0.1.Final/standalone/deployments: Too many open files
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixException.translateToIOException(UnixException.java:100)
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:111)
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:116)
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.newDirectoryStream(UnixFileSystemProvider.java:428)
    at java.base/java.nio.file.Files.newDirectoryStream(Files.java:603)
    at org.jboss.as.deployment-scanner@6.0.2.Final//org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner.FileSystemDeploymentService.listDirectoryChildren(FileSystemDeploymentService.java:1358)
    ... 11 more

2019-08-08 07:55:11,261 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (Thread-1) WFLYSRV0236: Suspending server with no timeout.
2019-08-08 07:55:11,272 INFO  [org.jboss.as.ejb3] (Thread-1) WFLYEJB0493: EJB subsystem suspension complete
2019-08-08 07:55:11,285 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (Thread-1) WFLYSRV0220: Server shutdown has been requested via an OS signal
2019-08-08 07:55:11,324 INFO  [org.jboss.as.mail.extension] (MSC service thread 1-8) WFLYMAIL0002: Unbound mail session [java:jboss/mail/Default]
2019-08-08 07:55:11,327 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 72) WFLYUT0022: Unregistered web context: '/service' from server 'default-server'
```

Comment: The answer is usually in the root cause of the stack trace: *"Caused by: java.nio.file.FileSystemException: /opt/wildfly-14.0.1.Final/standalone/deployments: Too many open files"* Have you already checked this?

Comment: Thanks for answer, i'm investigating this problem (Too Many Open Files) monitoring the server, but until now the server didn't suspended.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like some process may be your web server process is keeping files open and it is reaching beyond ulimit.
To find root cause, you can simply use lsof linux command to see all the open files and their respective process ids.
1) if you find you could control this count of open files, then it's good.
2) if it's unavoidable, then try increasing ulimit